# 'if' statement and eventListener question

Tags: javascript, event-handling, conditional-statements, addeventlistener

I'm building a website and right now I'm having an issue trying to get an if statement to read a change of state variable.

I'm trying to close my navbar menu when I click anywhere in the body, other than the navbar. However, my if statement that contains the event listener for the body will not execute because (I think) that the change of state variable that is being used for the condition (true when menu is open, false when menu is closed) is just not being read.

When I open the nav menu, the change of state variable changes to true, as it is intended to. When I close the menu using the button on the nav bar, the change of state variable changes to false, as it is intended to.

Here's my code:

```js
"use strict";

const btnNav = document.querySelector(".nav-btn--container");
const linkContainer = document.querySelector(".link-container");
const header = document.querySelector(".header");
const sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
const bodyChildren = header.parentElement.children;
const navBtn = document.querySelector(".nav-btn");
const menu = document.querySelector(".sidebar__menu");
const body = document.querySelector(".container");

/**** change of state variables ****/
let menuIsOpen = false;

/**** functions ****/
const closeMenu = function () {
  addRemoveBlur("remove");
  navBtn.classList.remove("nav-btn--opened");
  sidebar.classList.remove("blur");
  navBtn.classList.add("nav-btn--closed");
  menu.style.visibility = "hidden";
  menu.style.transform = "translateX(-150%)";
  menuIsOpen = false;
};

const openMenu = function () {
  addRemoveBlur("add");
  navBtn.classList.remove("nav-btn--closed");
  navBtn.classList.add("nav-btn--opened");
  menu.style.visibility = "visible";
  menu.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
  menuIsOpen = true;
};

const closeMenuByBody = function (e) {
  const click = e.target;
  closeMenu();
};

const openCloseMenu = function () {
  if (!menuIsOpen) {
    openMenu();
    return;
  }

  if (menuIsOpen) {
    closeMenu();
    return;
  }
};

/**** this is the problem ****/
if (menuIsOpen) {
  body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeMenuByBody(e);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the event listener is never initialized, as your `menuIsOpen` variable is always declared false.

You should switch your if statement to be contained within the click event handler, like so:

```js
body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (menuIsOpen) {
    closeMenuByBody(e);
  }
});
```

You should also consider the following changes to your `openCloseMenu` method (here renamed to `toggleMenu`):

```js
const toggleMenu = function () {
  if (menuIsOpen) {
    closeMenu();
  } else {
    openMenu();
  }
};
```

As you are evaluating a boolean value, there is no need to test it in two different `if` expressions: you check if it's true and do something if it is, or else you do something knowing that it's false.

You could also remove your `closeMenuByBody` method, and just call the `closeMenu` method from your event listener, as you aren't doing anything in it appart from that:

```js
body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (menuIsOpen) {
    e.preventDefault();
    closeMenu();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to this and now it's working:  `[const closeMenuByBody = function (e) {
  const navContents = sidebar.children;
  let clickedInNav = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < navContents.length; i++) {
    if (
      navContents[i] === e.target ||
      e.target === sidebar ||
      e.target === linkContainer
    )
      clickedInNav = true;
  }

  if (menuIsOpen && !clickedInNav) closeMenu();
};]`

Comment: @NikT great to hear! If my solution worked, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer

Comment: @NikT just added some extra modifications/improvements that could be done.